# SSRS and cached reports

Tags: caching, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm opening an SSRS2008 report using the http://server/reportserver/... syntax, outputting directly a PDF copy.  This report has several parameters.

The problem is that, despite making changes to the report, and clearing the browser's temporary files cache.. if I request the same report (i.e. same parameters) - the old report is returned.

In the report execution properties, I have "Always run this report with the most recent data" and "Do not cache temporary copies of this report" selected.

It's not just a case of caching data, but the entire report (including formatting, e.g. I deleted a page from the report yet it was still being shown...) and as I haven't specifically chosen to perform any caching I'm a little concerned and clearly don't fully understand what's going on!

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you change the report SSRS caches the data and does not reload it unless the parameters change.

If you have a time sensitive report, or during development you can add a parameter to force the reload and set the default value to =TimeOfDay().

This way SSRS always sees it as a new request.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to verify that you've properly deployed the modified report to the server.

Are you able to see the differences exporting to PDF vs. viewing it in the web SSRS Report Manager?